# How can I convert a StringMap to a List in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I am very new to OCaml and am trying to convert a StringMap to a List in OCaml.

The map was generated from a list previously.

```
let map = List.fold_left(<SOME CODE HERE, WHICH I AM OMITTING>
    ) StringMap.empty
    in StringMap.fold(fun w c newlist -> (c,w)::newlist) map[]
```

The last line in the code above gives me the following error:
This expression has type StringMap.key list -> int StringMap.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         'a StringMap.t = 'a Map.Make(String).t

Please note: This code is typed into an ocamllex file (.mll) and I get this error when I try to execute the lexical analyser (.ml) file generated.

Why am I getting this error? How do I get my code to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the `map` value has type `StringMap.key list -> int StringMap.t`, which means that it's a function, not a map as you expected it. Furthermore, the function signature tells you what was missing in the previous expression to get a `int StringMap.t` as you expected: you need to add a parameter to the call to `List.fold_left`, of type `StringMap.key list`, which I suppose is a `string list`:

```
let map = List.fold_left(<SOME CODE HERE, WHICH I AM OMITTING>
) StringMap.empty string_list
```

Where `string_list` is the missing parameter: the list of keys used to build your map.

Answer (score 2):

`StringMap.bindings` will return a list of `(key, value)` pairs.